# How to set an action to unpublish a comment with rules?

Tags: 7, rules

The rules modules has default actions setup to unpublish nodes but not comments.
Do I need to use PHP to unpublish a comment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you choose the action "Set a data value" and a comment is visible to the action (e.g. because the triggering event is "After saving a new comment") then the data selector will let you choose

```
comment:status
```

which you can then choose to set to "Published" or "Unpublished", or (via a data selection) to another available value.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue using Flag module and this solution worked out great for

the data source was *flagged-comment:status* in case anyone comes across this

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have nodecomment module downloaded and enabled. If node comment module is there, then you will get comments as the first option in rules trigger.

Comment: If you are referring to http://drupal.org/project/nodecomment, it doesn't have a D7 version, and @MotoTribe still doesn't tag his questions with D7 yet :) :) :)

Comment: oops, forgot again. Anybody still on 6? ;-)